# how to use pca in Matlab

Tags: matlab, pca

According to the manual, it says `[coeff,score,latent,tsquared,explained,mu] = pca(X)`. 
In my opinion, PCA is same as truncated SVD. But for the outputs of pca, which one is truncated eigenvectors and which one is truncated eigenvalues ?

Answer (score 0):

The `latent` output is the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix of `X`.

To specify the number of components, use the `'NumComponents'` option, e.g:

```
[coeff,score,latent,tsquared,explained,mu] = pca(X, 'NumComponents', 3);
```

---

Alternatively, you can use:

```
C = cov(X);
[eigenvectors,eigenvalues] = eig(C);
```

To get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.